# What is the process of "mini-tubbing"?

Tags: restoration

I heard someone mention they were considering "mini-tubbing" their restoration project car.

What does that mean?

Can you just "tub" a car, or can only "mini tub" one? Can you "maxi tub"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Hot Rod magazine:

> Mini-tubbing is the act of widening a car's rear wheelwells, moving the inner halves inboard to the location of the stock frame-rails to achieve maximum tire clearance without major frame hacking. It's a mod that dates back to the early '60s and has mostly been used for drag racing...

More here: http://www.hotrod.com/how-to/paint-body/hrdp-0903-diy-mini-tubbing-guide/